# Parallelize webpack builds to improve performance?

Tags: javascript, webpack

My webpack production builds take upwards of 70 seconds, but only uses one CPU core.

Is it possible to speed things up by running webpack builds across multiple cores in parallel? (like, ex, `make -j4`?)

Comment: Unlikely, but let's see other opinions :-)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [A recent issue on Webpack Github](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1679)

Basically, you can spawn a new worker for each entry, or collection of up to your number of cpus, like so:

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var os = require('os');

var entries = [...]; // your entries go here

module.exports = _.chunk(entries, os.cpus().length).map(function(entry) {
  return {
    entry: entry,
    ... rest of your config ...
  };
});
```

I found this hard to get to work, honestly, but I have a funky setup. Who doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

> parallel-webpack allows you to run multiple webpack builds in
>   parallel, spreading the work across your processors and thus helping
>   to significantly speed up your build.

Given a webpack.config.js like this:

```
var path = require('path');
module.exports = [{
    entry: './pageA.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: 'pageA.bundle.js'
    }
}, {
    entry: './pageB.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: 'pageB.bundle.js'
    }
}];
```

parallel-webpack will run both specified builds in parallel.

You can specify the parallel, or p for short, option to tell parallel-webpack how many CPUs it may use. Eg.

```
parallel-webpack -p=2
```

Other than this you can also make sure that stats are switched off. Generating stats is heavy work.
You can switch it off by using following:-

```
parallel-webpack --no-stats
```